# Is it possible to have more than four consecutive verbs in a sentence?

Tags: verbs, catenative-verbs

This is simply a question based on curiosity. I have tried to research different combinations of helping verbs and action verbs that contain more than four consecutive verbs, but I can't seem to find any. Here are the constraints for what I am looking for:

- The verbs must be consecutive.
- no compound verbs (So you can't have the following sentence or something like it: I ate chips, watched the telvision, went to the park, came home, and slept.)
- The verbs can be in any tense as long as they are grammatically correct.
- The verbs must be part of the same verb phrase (Joan, I know, will push herself as much as she can to accomplish her goals. "Know" and "will push" are not part of the same verb phrase.

Here's an example of what I am looking for:

> If you get out of the water now, you will have been afloat for a total of twenty minutes.

Does anyone think they know a verb phrase that has more than four consecutive verbs?

Comment: It's like puns vs. homophones: the sentence must make conceptual sense as well if you want full points

Comment: @RichardHaven To be honest, I don't care how crazy the sentence is. As long as the grammar is correct, semantics don't matter to me. Although, I see what you are saying.

Comment: You might get more responses if you have this question migrated to [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Lawrence Good idea!

Comment: Can't be migrated for two reasons: (1) technical: too old to migrate. (2) substantial: Puzzling.SE looks for challenges 'with a “best answer” criteria (as opposed to an open ended “Does anyone think they know of [any examples of]...”)'. Puzzling.SE say they can accept the puzzle if suitably reworded. If you want to try that, simply delete the question here and re-ask there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because this is a trivial time waster.

Comment: 'Let go' might be a useful [V + V] MWV to bear in mind.

Answer (score 3):

> The Government's argument that "no reasonable man **could** **have**
> **been** **left** **guessing** beforehand as to the position of that close but vivid boundary between `rhetoric and disloyalty to the
> United States'"[27] cites United States v. Harvey, 19 U.S.C.M.A. 539,
> 544 (1970). (Stolte v. Laird, 353 F. Supp. 1392 (D.D.C. 1972))

***could*** modal auxiliary - ***have*** marking the perfect - ***been*** marking the progressive - ***left*** catenative - ***guessing*** catenative complement

Comment: I think it's better to say that auxiliary verbs are also catenative, thus "have been left guessing" is catenative complement of "could"; "been left guessing" is catenative complement of "have", "left guessing" is catenative complement of "been", and "guessing" is complement of "left".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible:

> You should have dared go run help start trying to ask better questions.

It’s called using [catenative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs).

Don’t try this at home.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't understand this sentence, let me try to make it clearer. "You should have dared [someone] to go and run to [see if they can] help [someone] start trying to ask better questions." Unfortunately, there are not five consecutive verbs anywhere in this sentence as it contains many infinitives. Since infinitives are never verbs, this sentence doen't have five consecutive verbs. In fact, it doesn't even have four consecutive verbs in it. After reading the Wikipedia page on catenative verbs, I found no sentences with five consecutive verbs, but I did learn something new. Thanks!

Comment: First, you've misparsed the sentence: there's no someone involved. Second, I have no idea what you are talking about by pretending that infinitives "are not verbs"; that's crazy talk. Third, the only words in that sentence that are not verbs are *you*, *better*, and *questions* — and arguably *to*. The rest are all verbs, **all *nine* of them in a row**.

Comment: 1. http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/infinitive.htm 2. https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/verbals.html 3. http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/verbals.htm Those are just a few sources stating that infinitives are *not* verbs. Also, the [someone] was only added to help anyone else who read your sentence. All I did was make it more normal sounding. Also, although the infinitives aren't verbs, "to" is certainly not a verb. So, even if the infinitives were verbs, "to" would not be. So, that would not be nine in a row.

Comment: @JonathanHarbaugh Grammar monster says: “An infinitive **is** a verb form (often preceded by to, e.g., to dance, to sing) which ***can*** function as a noun, an adjective, or an adverb.”  and Towson University says “An infinitive is **a verbal formed by placing to** in front of the simple present form of a verb.” Where did you get the impression that infinitives are not verbs?

Comment: Eleven ?? "You should have dared to go run find help to start trying to resuscitate dying man."

Comment: @Mari-LouA http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/verbs.htm gives a better answer. They say that verbals are not true verbs as they are simply forms of verbs. Here, they are functioning as direct objects and adverbs. On top of that, if you look at my original question, I was hoping the verbs could be in the same verb phrase. Nevertheless, I appreciate tchrist attempting to answer as well as your contribution in the comments.

Comment: Where in the name did you find this grammatically correct or idiomatically correct that you heard it from a Native speaker’s mouth?

Answer (score 1):

The question is ill-phrased, for English at least. There are many ways to get lots of verbs in a sentence. Every clause has at least one verb, so with many clauses, complex sentences can have as many verbs as one wants.

"Consecutive" is a little different. The two example sentence contained no more than three consecutive verbs: *will have been*. *Afloat* is a predicate adjective, not a verb. And *get out of the water* contains only one verb, *get*.

The first part of an English verb phrase can contain up to four auxiliary verbs plus a main verb, in a particular order:

- `Modal` + *have* (`Perfect`) + *be* (`Progressive`) + *be* (`Passive`) + `Main verb`
  *She [should have been being interviewed] for the last 4 hours, but we'll check.*

Each auxiliary must be followed by a particular form of the next verb. The main verb may well be a verb that takes a complement clause that itself consists of verbs. Many, many constructions in English simply use serial verbs, like *go eat* or *stop shouting*. The auxiliary chain of at most 5 verbs applies to every tensed clause; idioms, though, are by their nature irregular and variable.

Answer (score 0):

Seven: I would have liked to have gone skiing were that an option.
Eight: Jane, I know, would have liked to have gone skiing should you have asked.

All grammatically correct. Infinitive is a verb tense, same as past, present, participle, and gerund forms.

Comment: Does 'to' count as a verb?

Comment: @Mitch It does if you're Geoff Pullum, or Ivan Saag or if you consult most modern HPSGers. A non-finite auxiliary verb to be more precise. Here is what is often considered one of the best expositions/defences of this position: [Levine 2012 *Auxiliaries:* To'*s company*](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/levine.1/publications/Levine_auxiliary_to.pdf)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. With all due respect to those guys (even after looking at the paper), that is insane. That's like saying 'the' is a noun because it only comes at the beginning of a noun phrase. I'm sure a well-reasoned case could be made for that too.

Comment: @Mitch But you've got to look at the evidence! Interesting fact: when I was teaching English to pre-int and elementary students a few years ago, I taught them that *to* was an auxiliary verb. It's heplful because one rampant mistake is students assuming that  VP ellipsis can happen after normal lexical verbs: A: Do want to come with us? B: Yes, I want! (urgh) The strange thing was that not one learner ever batted an eyelid or asked me about it. And they'd question almost everything else. [Re *the* being a noun. Yes, see Richard Hudson, well a pronoun anyway](https://tinyurl.com/yck7kmut)

Comment: @Mitch Or Mariangela Spinillo, 2004,  [Reconceptuallising the English determiner Class](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10101595/1/out.pdf). She argues that most 'determiner's are pronouns or adjectives or adverbs (but the central ones are pronouns and thus a special type of noun). Really good read!